# Blurry Dev C++ On Windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, ide, windows-10, scaling, dev-c++

90% of the apps are displaying correctly sharp and clear as it's supposed to be on my uhd laptop screen. My scaling is 150% (as default also) (because of uhd screen in 15.6" laptop, 100% is too inefficient for my eyes.)

But dev c++ and some old softwares are looking blurry.

[blurry dev c++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBNHk.png)

there is a fix on windows 10 settings named "advanced scaling" that is already enabled. is there any way to fix blurry dev c++ or do you recommend better up to date ide for c++ with compiler?

[advanced scaling settings windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRzKv.jpg)

(eclipse-cpp with mingw is slow, 
clion is super but uses visual c++ compiler (i dont know if is there any setting for compiler, 
microsoft visual c++ is good but showing some errors for nothing, actually says "no errors" than doesnt compiles for some time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right click on the Dev c++
2. Select “Properties” from the popup menu.
3. Click on “Compatibility” tab.

making the settings to manually fix fuzzy text in windows 10

4. Select “Override high DPI scaling behavior.
5. Select “**`System (Advanced)`**” **not** "System" or "Application" from the options provided in “Scaling performed by” section.
6. Click on “Apply” button and then on “OK.”

[Fixed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKa7r.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of Dev C++ compiled with the latest version of Delphi which supports high-DPI, Unicode, and Windows 10.

https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/releases